# JUnit tests on Netty 4.1 server / client

Tags: java, junit, netty

I have a `Netty 4.1.6` server and client that I wish to unit test using `JUnit`. Some of the tests I had in mind are:

- Check the connection of my client to my netty server.
- Check the receiving of input from my client to my server.
- Test the server-output of a 'help' command client-side.

I read of the use of `EmbeddedChannel`s in order to simulate a `Netty` channel, but how may I simply test both my server and client on each other?

Here's one of the few tests I have so far:

```
public void testNettyStringDecoder() {
    EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new StringDecoder(Charset.defaultCharset()));
    channel.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{(byte)0xE2,(byte)0x98,(byte)0xA2}));
    String myObject = channel.readInbound();

    assertEquals("☢", myObject);
    System.out.println("[NETTY] Tested our StringDecoder's ability to decone unicode." +
            " Expected ☢ got " + myObject);
}
```

Comment: You usually would write a integration test to test the client and server together, unit tests are make for small parts of the program, like simple classes

Comment: Note, make sure to follow licences when you copy code from the internet, you're not doing this for the code you posted and that can cause legal troubles in your final program

Comment: For your first comment: thank you, that's a better way of seeing it.
For the second one: being a student with a project I did not know I had to take this into account. But thank you, I will.